# Including user statistics for multiple views

Tags: python, django

I have a navigation bar that displays "login" and "register" when the user is not signed in. When the user is signed in, the navigation bar will display the user's name and the number of messages he has in his inbox.

The problem is that the navigation page is present on around 50 pages, so there are around 50 view functions that have to get the user information and send it to the template. If I want to change this later, it will be a pain!

For example, here is an example view:

```
def index(request):
  user = request.user
  ...
  return render_to_response("page.html", {'user': user})
```

I have to send the info about the user each time to any page with the navigation bar because my navigation bar contains the code:

```
{% if user %}
...
{% else %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

**Edit:** Also, I have a UserProfile model which I want to send through to the template. Is there a way to do this, too?

Comment: You need to pass a RequestContext to your template renderer so you can take advantage of context processors and the fact that request.user will be in your template context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to include `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` configuration in your `settings.py`. As described [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) it wil add a `user` and `perms` variable in your template context which gives you direct access to the current user.

Not that the default configuration for `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` is this (in Django 1.3):

```
("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

So the context processor should already be active und you should be able to access the `user` variable in you templates without returning it in the view.

In your views, you can simply use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut which will take care of creating the RequestContext instance that is needed:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html' )
```

Comment: Remember that you need to use a RequestContext to render the template, or use the 'render' shortcut which uses one internally.

Comment: Hello, is it possible for me to get access to the UserProfile model in addition to the user model?

Comment: @egidra you can simply do `user.get_profile.anyfield` in your views. get_profile() is a method of user that returns the profile. Django will automatically call it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom template tag, as DrTyrsa suggested, or you could create [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Comment: Can you show an example of context processor for this task? What should it add to context? Login form? Register link? Stats (what to add if a user isn't logged in)?

Comment: Your processor only needs to add data to the context that will be used in your template down the road.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Ok, can I see the implementation? My point is that context processor should just add objects to context, nothing more. Any logic, like deciding which object to add, when to add them and so on, should be placed in tags, it's much clearer and doesn't rise questions like "what processor gave me this object".

Comment: There is no need to write an own context processor since their is a build in one that does exactly what he wants. See my answer.

Comment: @DrTyrsa Thought the OP asked the question ; my bad. I think what one should use depends on the situation and that usually you should use both: context processors should provide the data and template tags the logic. Now, Django leaves us with enough freedom to have it our own way (And that's great).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Can I see the implementation of context processor, which will just "provide the data" in this situation?

Comment: If you need just some data in template, then probably context processor would be the best, the simplest solution. If you need some more logic then template tag will be required, or inclusion tag, or included template with some logic. Tool that fits the task better should be used. But it's not clear what question author needs exactly, so I added context processor option...

Comment: @DrTyrsa Data provided could be the messages queryset. But then, you could use a template tag to do that. You could even use a model method. Or you could include another template. And you could also use a template filter. What's your point ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to send user to every view, [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) contains the user, you can easily access it in template when you are logged in.

and another solution is, save the user in [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), and access it in any view or template.